# asp.net mvc core how can I return a Json query

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

First and foremost I Know how to return a Json Query by doing this

```
public JsonResult streams()
{
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Connectionstring))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var credentials =  conn.Query<Streams>("select id,name from streams").ToList();                
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
        conn.Close();
        return Json(credentials);
    }
}
```

That code above returns Json for me from the database, however now I am actually returning the Json from the SQL code by changing the query to this

```
var credentials =  conn.Query<Streams>("select SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(t)) from (select id,name from streams) t").ToList();
```

That new query works correctly however it is returning null in the Controller as I have it like this now

```
public JsonResult streams()
{
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Connectionstring))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var credentials =  conn.Query<Streams>("SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(t)) from (select id,name from streams) t").ToList();            
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
        conn.Close();
        return Json(credentials);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this ? My assumption is that using JsonResult and returning Json as an action is messing things up because the SQL query is already returning Json.

This is my Stream Class

```
  public class Streams
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int profile_id { get; set; }

        public DateTime created_on { get; set; }
        public int last_reply { get; set; }
        public int comments { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public float latitudes { get; set; }
        public float longitudes { get; set; }
        public int votes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is your SQL query (in second example) result set columns match with your Stream property names ? Can you share the result set ?

Comment: It does not and here is my stream names

Comment: Why are you returning json from your Sql query. Return the normal result set and Let Json method takes care of converting it to JSON format

Comment: I was under the impression that returning Json from the SQL code is more efficient than converting it to Json in the application, especially when there are a lot of requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have Json in your string and the call to `this.Json(object)` is designed to serialize it to Json.

In MVC 5 you could:

```
return this.Content(credentials, "application/json");
```

The [`ContentResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/8b1bd343ba56152d2a7e677cf041dc9d62b4033f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ContentResult.cs) class is in MVC Core, so I assume that the syntax remains the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is exactly what I needed