# How return Json from an ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need fill some dropdown combo so I create a WebApi and is working OK.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/States/FindMunicipalityByStateID")]
public IHttpActionResult FindMunicipalityByStateID(String StateID)
{
    List<MunicipalityModel> municipality  = db.municipality.Where(p => p.StateID == StateID)
                       .Select(p => new MunicipalityModel
                       {
                           Name = p.Name,
                           MunicipalityID = p.MunicipalityID
                       })
                       .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                       .ToList();

    if (municipality == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(municipality);
}
```

I read it using `JQuery.getJSON`, and also works fine:

```
$('#StateID').change(function () {
    var URL = 'http://myServer/myProject/api/States/FindMunicipalityByStateID?StateID=' + $('#StateID').val();
    
    $.getJSON(URL, function (data) {
        var items = '<option>Seleccione Municipio</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, municipality) {
            items += "<option value='" + municipality.WeekID + "'>" + municipality.Name + "</option>";                
        });
        $('#MunicipalityID').html(items);            
    });
});
```

The thing is now I want do the same but there is already an ASP.NET MVC controller from my EF wizard for that class so I try to do the same there.

I got 3 errors:

> The type or namespace name 'IHttpActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The name 'NotFound' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'Ok' does not exist in the current context

The first error can be solve with System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult.

Because can't add `using System.Web.Http;` because create conflicts with `using System.Web.Mvc;`

I saw a couple of related question:

Like this [IN MVC6 return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) ISSUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517210/in-mvc6-return-jsonrows-jsonrequestbehavior-allowget-issue) but this use a `JSonResult`

And this one [How to return JSON in a ASP.NET MVC/web controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452084/how-to-return-json-in-a-asp-net-mvc-web-controller) but this use a `Task<ActionResult>`

And neither handle the case when the object is not found.

Questions:

- Is there a reason WebApi controller doesn't need convert the result to JSON but an ASP.NET MVC controller does? Because my jQuery can read it just fine.
- Can I convert my WebApi code to ASP.NET MVC or need to use one of the examples?
- Do I need the `Not Found` result ?

Comment: mvc and web-api are 2 different things. If you want to return json in mvc, then you need to return a `JsonResult` (i.e `return Json(municipality, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well I don't want return a JsonResult just make it work. I assume because Im using `jQuery.getJson()` I need a Json. But didn't need anything speciall for WebApi work with the getJson. Also according to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353866/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-controller-and-web-api-controller-in-asp-net) now mvc and web-api are the same on mvc 6

Comment: You have not tagged this asp.net-core-mvc (the correct name for mvc6) - is that what you are using?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok I confess ignorance there. I always call it asp.net-mvc. Didnt know they change the name :(. Im using VS 2017 with all new packages. I assume is using mvc6. How can be sure?

Comment: @StephenMuecke mmm look like Im using mvc 5?  `<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />`

Comment: In that case, you must use `return Json(..);`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443521/asp-net-mvc-core-how-can-i-return-a-json-query

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well I will try to migrate to mvc 6. My fault by assuming that would be the default one :(